# Why django not display test result using unittest?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest

There is a problem when I test my Model using **unittest** module,which is that nothing was displayed when the process was succeed except for a string came from the "print".the result of my Iteration of the users didnt show up.What i was dong is below:

**1,models.py**

```
    class UserManager(models.Manager):
      def hah(self):
        return None
    class User(models.Model):
                id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
                email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
                password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
                logintime = models.IntegerField(default='')
                registertime = models.IntegerField()
                modifytime = models.IntegerField()
                loginip = models.CharField(max_length=60)
                islock = models.IntegerField()
                isavtive = models.IntegerField()
                activecode = models.CharField(max_length=45)
                role = models.CharField(max_length=1)

                objects = UserManager()
                class Meta:
                    db_table = 'user'
```

**2,serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','email','password','loginip')
```

**3,tests.py**

```
class UserModelTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def get_user(self):
        users = User.objects.all()
        userserializer = UserSerializer(users,many=True)
        print(userserializer.data)
        print(users)
        for row in users:
            print(row.email)
        print("this is user model test")
```

When I ran `python3.4 ./manage.py test user.tests.UserModelTest.get_user` ,the results were:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
[]
[]
this is user model test
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Did i miss something or any misunderstanding about unittest? And I notice someone has the same problem,what they are suggested to do is add `-- -s` option,but not work for me.And any solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't unit test look for methods that begin with "test_"? What happens if you change the name to test_get_user?

Comment: yeah,it does,but it can be specified to a full path even without a prefix "test_",and i tried your method,but not work!

Comment: Do you have a setUp method instantiating objects in the test database?

Comment: no,i didnt have one,i just noticed this basic for testing,but,can unittest use the actual database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the correct display but you didn't write any tests.
There are few things you should know to be able to write Unit tests:

1. your test functions should start with the word test such as `test_get_user_query`, this is to make your tests callable from:
   `./manage.py test appName` so you don't have to reference the whole path to the test.
2. The database used in unit tests is isolated from your development database, which means that it's completely empty and you need to populate it each time you want to test it, for your example you should add a line like this at the start of `get_user` or at a `setUp()` function:
   `User.objects.create(email='exp@me.com', password='somepass'....)` (populate the rest) so you can query it later
3. Use asserts to write your tests, you shouldn't use print, here's an example:

> ```
> class UserModelTest(unittest.TestCase):
>     def test_get_user_and_data_is_serialized(self):
>         User.objects.create(email='exp@me.com', password='somepass'....)
>         user = User.objects.all()[0]  # start testing one entry.
>         self.assertEqual(user.email, 'exp@me.com', 'Incorret email') # message when test fails
>         serialized_user = UserSerializer(users,many=False)
>         self.assertEqual(userserializer.data, {'email': 'exp@me.com', ....}, 'oops the data is not serialized')
> ```

Just change the data you are testing against, this is just an example

There is much more to know about unittest module, Read this if you need more help https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Also check this book by Harry J.W.Percival, one great resource:
http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/

Hope this helps!

Comment: very good explanation,I will dive deep into it :) Thanks very much!

Comment: i recommend you read this book, i'm currently following it up, best you can find out there http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/